# Is there a language with subroutines but no local variables?

Tags: programming-languages, function, scope

I'm wondering if anyone if aware of a language that has support for variables (that could be considered 'global'), and subroutines (functions), but without a concept of parameter passing, local scope, etc.  Something where every subroutine has access to every global variable, and only global variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BASIC and assembly come immediately to mind.

Of course, this is not construed as a feature.  That's why we invent conventions for which global variables should be used for parameter passing.

Comment: Even assembly has the convention of passing parameters by pushing them onto the stack...